# How to create custom module from scratch in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

1. How to create custom module from scratch in Magento 1.9.x.
2. which is the directory structure and which are the files i need to create for creating the simple basic custom module.

Comment: You can use this link:
https://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Comment: I want to develop custom  module without using silk software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with app/code/local directory and there build your module.

Create:
app/code/local/Vendor_Name/Module_Name/etc/config.xml
 with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Vendor_Name_Module_Name>
<version>0.0.1</version>
</Vendor_Name_Module_Name>
</modules>
</config>
```

and create app/etc/modules/_.xml
with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Vendor_Name_Module_Name>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
</Vendor_Name_Module_Name>
</modules>
</config>
```

With this 2 files you should be able to see your module in **Magento Admin > System Configuration > Advanced > Advanced**

Comment: thank you, but i want to create custom module for crud operation in magento back-end one new menu as well as admin can view,edit and delete FAQ's will be created and in front-end i need to create one form for FAQ.

Comment: Sure, but you asked about creating simple basic module.
I advise you to create a new question with more accurate description :)